# Selectively disable code reformatting on commit in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, restructuredtext

I am using PhpStorm 10.0 for a PHP project, with a Sphinx `documentation` directory inside, containing source `*.rst` files.

When I commit these .rst files, with the "Reformat code" option checked, PhpStorm erases the indentations in the .rst files. As Sphinx relies on these indentations, I can't build the documentation anymore...

I would like to keep "Reformat code" checked, because it is useful for the other types of files (php, js, etc..), but disable reformatting for the .rst files.

Is there a way to do this? Or to disable reformatting for the entire `documentation` directory?

Comment: I believe it is not possible (not 100% sure though): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136500 , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-3347, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66350

Comment: Thanks for the links. It seems effectively it isn't possible...